# log-likelihood cost function: mean or sum?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, theano

In [this code](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/d2764f288b4e58e12bd492953d1c1a0b43d92e21/code/logistic_sgd.py#L118-L135) for computing the negative log-likelihood they say:

> Note: we use the mean instead of the sum so that the learning rate is
>   less dependent on the batch size

and this is how they get the negative log-likelihood:

```
return -T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

This is true in many textbooks (e.g. *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* by Bishop), the negative log-likelihood is calculated by using the **sum** of each individual sample error rather than the **mean**. I still don't understand the note from the author. Every time when we calculate cost function should we use the mean rather than the sum? Even when we are not using batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the mean and the sum is just the multiplication by 1/N.

The problem with using the sum is that the batch size (N) will influence your gradients. The learning rate indicates how much in the direction of the gradient you want to adjust your parameters.

If your gradient is larger for larger batch sizes (N), it means that you will need to adjust the learning rate as you increase the batch size (N).

In practice, in order to keep these two (learning rate and batch size) independent, it is common to use the mean instead of the sum. This makes the gradient magnitude independent of N.

If you are not using a batch, then N=1 and the mean is the same as the sum.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if I use batch and the sum, not the mean? if I can adjust my learning rate and not change the batch size, It's okay doesn't it? or should i still use the mean?

Comment: If you adjust the learning rate accordingly, it should be the same. If you are decaying the learning rate, remember to adjust how you decay it too.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two situations when you want to change the batch size of your algorithm lets say from 10 to 100:

- If you are using the sum of the log-likelihood cost function the average step that you're taking will be multiplied by 10 (because the sum will have 10x more terms) and then you will have to readjust the learning rate
- If you are using the mean, then that result will be divided by 100 instead of 10, and your steps will be naturally of the same order of magnitude

So, if you're not using mini-batches or adjusting the batch size, don't worry about this